How to capture video in different resolutions from camera2 using surface？
There are three questions to how to output a camera video stream to a specified surface, the first scenario is that it doesn't match the original aspect ratio but the resolution is in the output list, the second scenario is that it matches the original aspect ratio but the resolution isn't in the output resolution list, and the third scenario is that it neither matches the aspect ratio nor is it in the output resolution list anymore.
Assuming that my camera's Raw/Active sensor has an Aspect of 4:3, and it has 1920x1080 in the list of output resolutions, how do I request a 1920x1080 surface output?
Assuming that my camera's Raw/Active sensor's Aspect is 4:3 and its output resolution list does not contain 1920x1440, how do I request a 1920x1440 surface output?
Assuming that my camera's Raw/Active sensor's Aspect is 4:3, and its list of output resolutions does not include 1440x900, how do I request a 1440x900 surface output?
I mean, how to construct the CaptureRequest, like whether it is required or not, and how to set CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION. Is the crop region related to the raw sensor size? Assuming I've set my Surface to the required size (it comes from the right target size surfaceTexture)

1. Requesting a 1920x1080 Surface Output (Aspect Ratio Doesn't Match, but Resolution is in the List)
If the camera's raw sensor is 4:3, but you want to output 1920x1080 (which has a 16:9 aspect ratio), this is how you would approach it:

CaptureRequest Setup:   The raw sensor's aspect ratio is 4:3, so when requesting 1920x1080, you will need to adjust the crop region.

SCALER_CROP_REGION:   This setting will crop the raw image from the sensor to fit the 1920x1080 resolution. You can calculate the crop region based on the difference in aspect ratios.
// e.g., 1280x960 (4:3)

Size sensorSize = getRawSensorSize(); 
// Define the output resolution (e.g., 16:9)
Size outputSize = new Size(1920, 1080);
// Calculate the crop region
Rect cropRegion = calculateCropRegion(sensorSize, outputSize);

// Set the CaptureRequest with the SCALER_CROP_REGION
CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder = 
cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, 
cropRegion);


Crop Region Calculation: The crop region should scale the 4:3 sensor resolution to match the 16:9 aspect ratio of 1920x1080.


You can calculate this based on the output resolution relative to the sensor resolution
